# Chef Opensource Server gives error on 'execute[initctl status private-chef-runsvdir]'

Tags: chef-infra

I am using opensource Chef-Server. I wanted to upgrade my server to the latest version. I downloaded the latest .deb file and ran `dpkg -i chef-server-core_12.1.0-1_amd64.deb`
After that `chef-server-ctl upgrade`
Now while executing i got error on this execute statement `execute[initctl status private-chef-runsvdir]`
Can someone please tell me what is the issue over here.
Please look at the error part in the execution log

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[initctl status private-chef-runsvdir]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of initctl status private-chef-runsvdir ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: initctl: Unknown job: private-chef-runsvdir
---- End output of initctl status private-chef-runsvdir ----
Ran initctl status private-chef-runsvdir returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/opscode/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/enterprise/recipes/runit_upstart.rb

 34: execute "initctl status #{project_name}-runsvdir" do
 35:   retries 30
 36: end
 37: 

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/opscode/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/enterprise/recipes/runit_upstart.rb:34:in `from_file'

execute("initctl status private-chef-runsvdir") do
  action :run
  retries 30
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :execute
  command "initctl status private-chef-runsvdir"
  backup 5
  returns 0
 declared_type :execute
  cookbook_name "enterprise"
  recipe_name "runit_upstart"
end


Running handlers:
[2015-07-15T11:45:07+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-07-15T11:45:07+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 74.163193986 seconds
[2015-07-15T11:45:07+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/opscode/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
```

Comment: If a machine already had chef on it, then installing a server gives an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Installing chef server on a chef server will upgrade its version. I just did this 4 separate times with rpms on OEL 6.5.

One issue I ran int on chef server 12.1 was if any service was running when I went to do the install. Try

```
chef-server-ctl stop
chef-server-ctl upgrade
```

to see if that will work. You also might want to use chef-server-core 12.2.1-1 instead as it seems far more stable.

Comment: I tried that a multiple times on a ubuntu based machine, but nothing owrks

Comment: I know that Chef has come out with a new installer since I ran into my issue, which didn't have the same issues any of the times I used it.

Looking at your command, shouldnt it be a chef-server command though? Or is this happening before you do the chef 12 install at all?

Comment: It is a chef-server command "chef-server-ctl". And yes i tried with version previous than 12 but still the same issue